# fplot not plotting an exponential function

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, exponential

I'm trying to plot this function 0.5*sinc(n/2)*e^(0.5*j*n*pi*t) using this code:

```
n = 1;
x2t = @(t) 0.5*sinc(n/2)* exp(sqrt(-1)*n*pi*0.5*t);
fplot(x2t);
```

but I only get blank results, what's the problem?

Comment: Have you considered giving it the interval? `fplot(x2t,[tmin tmax])`?

Comment: Instead of `sqrt(-1)`, write `1i` or `1j`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function produces a complex result, and `fplot` does not plot that properly. Instead, you could plot the real and imaginary components separately:

```matlab
n = 1;
x2t = @(t) 0.5*sin(n/2)/(n/2) * exp(1i*n*pi*0.5*t);
fplot(@(t)real(x2t(t)));
hold on
fplot(@(t)imag(x2t(t)));
```

---

Notice that I replaced `sinc(n/2)` with `sin(n/2)/(n/2)`, since I don't have the `sinc` function in my version of MATLAB. I also replaced `sqrt(-1)` with the simpler `1i`.